# The support of the Schwarz rearrangement of a compactly supported function

Tags: integration, lebesgue-measure, support-function, decreasing-rearrangements

Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ a measurable set of finite measure. We define $E^\ast$, the symmetric rearrangement of $E$ to be
$$
E^\ast := B_R(0), R = \left(\frac{|E|}{|B|}\right)^{\frac{1}{N}}.
$$
Notice that $|E| = |E^\ast|$. Consider $f : \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ a Borel measurable function that vanish at infinity, that is, for every $t > 0$, the sets $\{|f| > t\}$ are of finite measure. Then its spherically symmetric and decreasing rearrangement, $f^\ast$, is defined on $\mathbb{R}^N$ by
$$
f^\ast(x) = \int_0^\infty \chi_{\{|f| > t\}^\ast} (x) dt.
$$
Now assume $f$ has support in the annulos $A_{\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2} = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : \epsilon _1< |x| < \epsilon_2\}$. I am trying to discover what should be the support of $f^\ast$. I know how to prove that, at least, $\text{supp}(f^\ast) \subset B_{\epsilon_2}$. To see this, notice first that, for all $t > 0$
$$
\{|f| > t\} := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^N : |f(x)| > t\} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^N :  \epsilon_1 <|x| <\epsilon_2 \text{ and } |f(x)| > t\},
$$
because it is impossible to happen  $|f(x)| > t$ for $|x| \leq \epsilon_1$ or $|x| \geq \epsilon_2$. Thus
$$
\{|f| > t\} \subset B_{\epsilon_2}.
$$
So, $|\{|f| > t\}| \leq |B_{\epsilon_2}| = |B| \epsilon_2^{N} $. Therefore, if $|x| \geq \epsilon_2$ then
$$
|B| |x|^N \geq |B| \epsilon_2^N \geq  |\{|f| > t\}|, \quad \forall t > 0.
$$
From which we obtain
$$
|x| \geq \left( \frac{|\{|f| > t\}|}{|B|}\right)^{\frac{1}{N}}
$$
In other words, $x \not\in \{|f| > t\}^\ast = B_R, \quad R = \left( \frac{|\{|f| > t\}|}{|B|}\right)^{\frac{1}{N}}.$
Finally
$$
\chi_{\{|f| > t\}^\ast}(x) = 0, \quad \forall t > 0
$$
and
$$
f^\ast(x) = \int_0^{+\infty} \chi_{\{|f| > t\}^\ast}(x) dt = 0 ,\quad |x| \geq \epsilon_2.
$$
Now I wonder if I can conclude that $f^\ast(x) = 0$ for $|x| \leq \epsilon_1$, but I don't know how to prove it.